# Why does my Sidekiq job fail from a model's after_commit code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

When I run this Sidekiq job, it successfully creates the Foo record. But because Foo's `after_commit` raises an error, the entire job fails and ends up in the dead job queue. If I fix the `after_commit` error and rerun the job, it will create another Foo record (or will do so on retry ), which is NOT desirable.

I expect `PerformAndCreateFooJob` to complete successfully after the Foo record is successfully created. The `after_commit` logic should not cause the job to fail.

- Why is the `after_commit` considered part of this job?
- Is there a way to decouple the `after_commit` code from the job?
- If no way to decouple, is there a better pattern to employ?

```rb
class PerformAndCreateFooJob
  include Sidekiq::Job
  sidekiq_options retry: 0

  def perform = Foo.create
end
```

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  after_commit -> () { raise }
end
```

[image: dead job queue showing Perform and create foo job failed]

Comment: after_commit is part of create and thus if it raises an error, the job will fail. dependening on what you want and why it fails and why you want to "allow" it to fail, you should rescue that error either in the after_commit code or in the job

Comment: _"is there a better pattern to employ"_ – to do what, exactly? Why is there a `raise` inside `after_commit` in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Stefan is there a better way to decouple the `after_commit` logic so that the job doesn't fail after it has ostensibly, ahem... _done its job_ :) The explicit `raise` is a concise way for readers to know that the `after_commit` logic errors (but the implementation details are not relevant to this post). You could imagine it kicking off another job, but suppose calling that job fails.

Comment: @aaronkelton `after_commit` raises an exception when `create` is called. Because of that exception, Sidekiq concludes that it has _not_ done its job and therefore retries. If you don't want Sidekiq to retry, you can just `rescue` the exception from `after_commit`.

Comment: Regarding "decoupling" – I find it difficult to come up with a suggestion here. An exception usually indicates some kind of error. `after_commit` on the other hand is executed after the database transaction succeeded. Raising an exception from the callback that is called upon success seems contradictory to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the `after_commit` considered part of this job?

Because it's part of `create` (actually part of `save`), which you're calling.

> Is there a way to decouple the `after_commit` code from the job?

By [using `insert`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert) to skip the callbacks as [explained in the guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks)

> If no way to decouple, is there a better pattern to employ?

Worth adding... it's best practice to [ensure jobs are idempotent](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#2-make-your-job-idempotent-and-transactional). There are many reasons a job can be retried, including your own app logic, but also other system conditions.  In normal circumstances, this could be as simple as using a `find_by` first (assuming your job queuing logic is unlikely to create many jobs for the same record/data), or maybe needs a unique constraint in the DB and logic to rescue a failure there.